# Populating a multidimensional vector during runtime

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

Clearly this isn't working so the code is wrong, but how do I fix it?
This whole thing could be wrong for all I know lol, but I'm trying to create a multidimensional vector that creates itself during runtime. I get an error: `vector subscript out of range`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
   int row = 0, col = 0;
   std::cout << "Size of Row: "; std::cin >> row; 
   std::cout << "Size of Column: "; std::cin >> col;

   std::vector<std::vector<int>> td;
   td.resize(row * col);

   for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++){
        td[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate the appropriate amount of memory to the vector of vectors. Instead of resizing it, you can explicitly set the amount empty rows and columns with the following code.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > td(row+1, std::vector<int>(col+1)); 
//+1 is needed because the loop you created is <=
```

Otherwise, you can adjust the loop and do the following:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > td(row, std::vector<int>(col));

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
    td[i][j];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
td.resize(row * col);
```

the first dimension of `td` will be `row*col`, but its second dimension are still empty. That's why you got the error.

You should use

```
td.resize(row); // set first dimension
for (int i=0; i<row; i++) // set each second dimenstion
    td[i].resize(col);
```

or simply

```
vector<vector<int>> td(row, vector<int>(col)); // has rows, each of them has cols
```

Answer (score 2):

td refers to the outer vector, so your resize creases a vector of row'col empty vectors.  You'll need to resize that to just row instead, then your for i loop can say td[i].resize(col) inside to make it two dimensional.